# notation in definition of range and domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In my set theory book (A book of set theory, Charles,C,Pinter) domain and range of graph $G$ is defined by

$dom G=\{x:\exists y \ni (x,y)\in G\}$
$ran G=\{y:\exists x \ni (x,y)\in G\}$

But I don't know what $\exists x \ni (x,y)$ exactly means. Ordered pair is defined with $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ so $x\in \{x\}\in \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}=(x,y)$. I think we should write $x \in (x,y)$ instead of $x \ni (x,y)$
What makes that definition possible?

Comment: The second symbols is "such that".

Comment: $\exists y \ni (x,y)\in G$ read as "there exists $y$ such that $(x,y)\in G$ "

Comment: The first one should say: There exists y with the property that (x,y) is a member of G. (Not necessarily in those exact words). Normally I would expect to bracket  or a vertical line where the backwards epsilon appears. It may be a typo in the book. Does he give a definition of his use of this symbol? BTW there is another widely-used def;n of (x,y) , namely $\{x, \{x,y\}\}$.

Comment: pls see: https://books.google.de/books?id=q1KVAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA90&hl=de&pg=PA24&output=embed"width=500 height=500

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan First, thanks for what symbol means. Second, is {{x},{x,y}} a set because {x} and {x,y} are set? and x is an element of {x} and {x} is an element of {{x},{x,y}}. Is there something wrong with my idea?

Comment: @TheCount  Thanks!

Comment: Formally, $x\in(x,y)$ is not correct, but that's also not important. You just want some definition of the pair such that from the pair you can conclude what the value of the first coordinate and what the value of the second coordinate is. It is a common exercise in set theory to prove $\forall x,y,z,u ((x,y)=(z,u)\rightarrow (x=z\wedge y=u))$.
There is no connection between $\in$ and $\ni$ in meaning.
Your reasoning why $(x,y)$ is a set, is correct. If you know ZFC, it uses the Pairing and the Separation Axioms.

Comment: @noobgi You're welcome. Another common (more common, to me, but some will differ) notation is "s.t.".

Comment: @martin.koeberl I agree with x∈(x,y) is not important. But is that mean x is not an element of {{x},{x,y}}?

Comment: Oh yes, I was referring to this definition. The axiom of Foundation implies this.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Thanks! Now I understood why my idea is wrong by axiom